# How to get a list of Jenkins builds that ran at a particular time?

Tags: jenkins, jobs, jenkins-api, jenkins-agent

My current Jenkins has a large number of jobs. Different folders, each with multiple jobs. I recently saw that one Jenkins slave(which is auto-scaled) is sending too many requests to another server at a particular time. However, I am unable to find which builds are run at that particular time without manually checking them. Is there any way to get this information using the API/Groovy script?

Comment: In my answer you'll find a simple python script which gets this information via Jenkins API. Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a very small bash script to run on the jenkins server to parse through the logfiles.

It is not sufficient to look only at the job start time. A job could have started just before your time window and even ended after your time window; it would still have run within your time window.

```
#!/bin/bash
start=$1
end=$2

for build_xml in jobs/*/branches/*/builds/*/build.xml
do
        startTime=$(sed -n -e "s/.*<startTime>\(.*\)<\/startTime>.*/\1/p" $build_xml)
        modificationTime=$(date '+%s' -r $build_xml)
        if [[ $modificationTime > $start ]] && [[ $startTime < $end ]]
        then
                echo "START $(date -d @${startTime::-3})   END $(date -d @$modificationTime)   : $build_xml"
        fi
done
```

usage:

```
./getBuildsRunningBetween.sh 1565535639 1565582439
```

would give:

```
START Sun Aug 11 20:29:00 CEST 2019   END Sun Aug 11 20:30:20 CEST 2019   : jobs/job-name/branches/branch-name/builds/277/build.xml
```

Comment: If the jobs/pipelines are not "branched", removing the `branches/*` from the for loops works well.

Comment: Also need to add quotations around `$build_xml` in case your job names have spaces. `"$build_xml"` in lines 7 and 8.

Answer (score 1):

Running jobs can be found based on color categorization called anime, using the below Jenkins API.

> "Jenkins host url"/api/xml?tree=jobs[name,url,color]&xpath=/hudson/job[ends-with(color/text(),%22_anime%22)]&wrapper=jobs

Blue ones are the ones that are running

> blue_anime

Comment: I dont want currently running builds, but build from a past day. For eg, if i want to see which jobs ran yesterday between 1pm and 2 pm(The time of high load). Can I use the API to do that?

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily achieved with a simple python script and Jenkins JSON REST API.

**1.Prerequisites**

Python 2.7 or 3.x and [python requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library installed:

`pip install requests`

For python 3.x

`pip3 install requests`

Also: [How to install pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/)

**2.Python script to fetch builds between dates**

```python
import requests
from datetime import datetime


jenkins_url = "JENKINS_HOST"
username = "USERNAME"
password = "PASSWORD"
job_name = "JOB_NAME"
stop_date = datetime.strptime('23.11.2018 0:30:00', "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")        
start_date = datetime.strptime('10.11.2018 18:46:04', "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S") 
request_url = "{0:s}/job/{1:s}/api/json{2:s}".format(
    jenkins_url,
    job_name,
    "?tree=builds[fullDisplayName,id,number,timestamp,url]"
)

response = requests.get(request_url, auth=(username, password)).json()
builds = []

for build in response['builds']:
    build_date = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(build['timestamp']/1000)
    if build_date >= start_date and build_date <= stop_date:
        builds.append(build)
        print("Job name: {0:s}".format(build["fullDisplayName"]))
        print("Build number: {0:d}".format(build["number"]))
        print("Build url: {0:s}".format(build["url"]))
        print("Build timestamp: {0:d}".format(build["timestamp"]))
        print("Build date: {}\n".format(build_date))
```

Above script works both with python 2.7 and 3.x. Now a little explanation:

First download all builds data by using JSON API and load response as JSON. Then for each build convert its timestamp to date time and compare with start and stop dates. Please note its important to divide timestamp by 1000 to get seconds not milliseconds (otherwise date conversion from timestamp will raise a ValueError).

Example output:

```bash
$ python test.py 
Job name: Dummy #21
Build number: 21
Build url: http://localhost:8080/job/Dummy/21/
Build timestamp: 1541875585881
Build date: 2018-11-10 18:46:25

Job name: Dummy #20
Build number: 20
Build url: http://localhost:8080/job/Dummy/20/
Build timestamp: 1541875564250
Build date: 2018-11-10 18:46:04
```

On the other hand, if you want to provide start and stop dates in a different format then remember you'll need to adjust format parameter it in `strptime()` function. [Python datetime directives.](http://strftime.org/)

Few examples:

```python
datetime.strptime("23.11.2018", "%d.%m.%Y")
datetime.strptime("2018.11.23", "%Y.%m.%d")
datetime.strptime("Jun 1 2005  1:33PM", "%b %d %Y %I:%M%p")
```

**3.Python script to fetch build on exact date**

If you are interested in finding build by its exact date just replace this line:

```python
if build_date >= start_date and build_date <= stop_date:
```

with this:

```python
if build_date == date:
```

where `date` is particular build date.

**Please note!** that if you want to find build by exact date you'll need to provide `date` with the proper format. In this case it's `"%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S"`. Example:

```python
datetime.strptime('10.11.2018 18:46:04', "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Otherwise, even though dates will the same to a certain point (minutes, hours, date etc.) for python it won't be equal dates.

If you want to provide another format then you'll need to adjust it for `build_date` variable.

```python
build_date.strftime('%d %m,%Y')
```

Comment: This is nice if you know the build, but I believe the OP was asking to find any builds within the time window, since they don't know which build might be making the rogue requests.